# remove consecutive multi-line duplicates (with bash)

Tags: bash, sed, uniq

In a text file, I want to remove duplicates spanning two lines. Meaning in four consecutive lines the first two are the same as the last two. I only want to keep the first (or last) two lines. I want to preserve the order of lines in the file.

### Example

Consider a file `input.txt` where `foo\nbar` is repeated and `baz\nboo` is repeated, each in consecutive two-line blocks.

```
1
foo
bar
foo
bar
2
3
baz
boo
baz
boo
4
```

desired contents:

```
1
foo
bar
2
3
baz
boo
4
```

### Things considered: `uniq`, `sed`

The same task is fairly simple for removing single line duplicates: `uniq input.txt`. However, `man uniq` doesn't suggest that there is an option to get it to work for my use case.

I also had a look at [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html), but couldn't get it to work. EDIT: didn't try anything specific as [these docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html) only consider searching and replacing within a two-lines block, not four lines.

Comment: please update the question with the actual code you've tried; also, is it ***always*** 2 lines duplciated twice (`2x4`) or could it be 2 lines duplicated 3 times (`2x3`), or perhaps 1 line duplicated 4 times (`1x4`), or maybe 3 lines duplicated 2 times (`3x2`)?

Comment: It's always two lines that are duplicated. As mentioned 1 lines duplicates (`1*x`) are fairly easy to remove with `uniq`.
I edited the questions a bit clarifying that I didn't actually try anything. Thanks for your feedback @mark-fuso. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accept a `perl` solution then:

```bash
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.+\R.+\R)\1/$1/g' file

1
foo
bar
2
3
baz
boo
4
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `-E` (EREs) and `-z` (read the whole file into memory):

```
$ sed -Ez 's/((.*\n){2})\1/\1/g' file
1
foo
bar
2
3
baz
boo
4
```

I also think you need GNU sed for the backreference in the regexp as I don't think that's part of POSIX but I'm not 100% sure on that one.

Comment: Thank you! This works great for small files. However, it's unreasonably slow for the file that I'm using this for: ~2.5k lines, ~200KB. I upvoted, but will accept the perl answer. :)

Comment: I'm very surprised the perl version is faster as they're both doing the same thing but perl uses a PCRE regexp engine which is notoriously much slower than the ERE regexp engine used by sed. Oh well... Actually, I wonder if changing the regexp from `((.*\n){2})` to `(.+\n.+\n)` would make any difference. If you try that out and get a result I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: I should've been more precise in my previous comment: I was so impatient that I never even waited for the command to finish. I changed it now as suggested, but it still doesn't finish - I waited probably at least a minute this time. Maybe there is another issue?

Comment: A file such as you described (~2.5k lines, ~200KB) should be processed in a couple of seconds. Are you piping to sed or opening a file with sed? The only thing that springs to mind is sed might be hung waiting for input.

Comment: sorry for the late response, holidays...
This is how I'm using this:
`sed -Ez 's/((.*\n){2})\1/\1/g' "${FILE_TO_BE_CLEANED}" > "${tmp_file}"`
`mv "${tmp_file}" "${FILE_TO_BE_CLEANED}"`